# Splitting Overlapping date range in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I have following overlapping promotion running on item whose original price is 229

| Start_date | End Date | Discount_pecent | Original_Retail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Dec-23 | 14-Dec-23 | 10 | 229 |
| 12-Dec-23 | 16-Dec-23 | 20 | 229 |

I want to split this into below

| Start_date | End Date | Discount_pecent | Original_Retail | Promo_Retail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Dec-23 | 11-Dec-23 | 10 | 229 | 206.1 |
| 12-Dec-23 | 14-Dec-23 | 20 | 229 | 164.8 (20 % applied on 206.1) |
| 15-Dec-23 | 16-Dec-23 | 20 | 229 | 183.2 (10% applied on 229) |

whereas, the discount during overlap period should be cumulative: i.e first 10% should be applied then 20%

I used below query for date split, but i am not able to calculate the promo_retail

```
with cte1 as
(
  select promo_id, percent,  start_date as marker_date, 1 as type, b.item, b.SIMPLE_PROMO_RETAIL,
   SELLING_RETAIL
  from Table_A b
  union all
  select promo_id,percent, end_date+1 as marker_date, -1 as type, b.item, b.SIMPLE_PROMO_RETAIL 
, SELLING_RETAIL 
  from Table_A b
),
cte2 as (
  select promo_id, marker_date as begin_date,
    lead(marker_date) over (order by marker_date) - 1 as end_date,
    item, percent, SIMPLE_PROMO_RETAIL, SELLING_RETAIL,
    sum(type) over (order by marker_date) as periods
  from cte1
)
select a.promo_id, a.begin_date, a.end_date,a.item ,a.SELLING_RETAIL, 
a.percent,periods 
from cte2 a 
where a.end_date is not null and periods > 0;
```

Comment: Your edit is a significant change to the problem and should be a new question. I've rolled it back to the previous edit but you can see your change [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77638135/4) and copy it to a new question.

Comment: Hi @MT0 - I have created new question as requested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77644005/splitting-of-overlapping-date-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT` the start- and end-dates so that the start-date corresponds with a positive discount and the end-date an equal negative discount and then find the cumulative total of the discounts over time and then use the `LEAD` analytic function to find the next change in discount:

#### Additive discounts

If your discount amounts are additive (i.e. a 10% and a 20% discount gives a 30% total discount) then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT original_retail,
         dt AS start_date,
         LEAD(dt)
           OVER (PARTITION BY original_retail ORDER BY dt)
           - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS end_date,
         SUM(type*discount) OVER (
           PARTITION BY original_retail
           ORDER BY dt
         ) AS discount,
         TO_CHAR(
           original_retail
           * ( 100
             - SUM(type*discount) OVER (
                 PARTITION BY original_retail
                 ORDER BY dt
               )
             )
           / 100,
           'fm999990.00'
         ) AS promo_retail
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT (
    (dt, discount) FOR type IN (
      (start_date, discount_percent) AS +1,
      (end_date,   discount_percent) AS -1
    )
  )
)
WHERE  start_date < end_date;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Start_date, End_Date, Discount_percent, Original_Retail) AS
SELECT DATE '2023-12-10', DATE '2023-12-14', 10, 229 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-12-12', DATE '2023-12-16', 20, 229 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ORIGINAL_RETAIL | START_DATE | END_DATE | DISCOUNT | PROMO_RETAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 229 | 2023-12-10 00:00:00 | 2023-12-11 23:59:59 | 10 | 206.10 |
| 229 | 2023-12-12 00:00:00 | 2023-12-13 23:59:59 | 30 | 160.30 |
| 229 | 2023-12-14 00:00:00 | 2023-12-15 23:59:59 | 20 | 183.20 |

---

#### Multiplicative discounts

If your discounts are multiplicative (i.e. applying a 20% discount after a 10% discount results in 0.9 * 0.8 = 0.72 which gives a 28% total discount) then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT original_retail,
         dt AS start_date,
         LEAD(dt)
           OVER (PARTITION BY original_retail ORDER BY dt)
           - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS end_date,
         100
         - ROUND(
           EXP(
             SUM(
               LN(
                 CASE type
                 WHEN 1
                 THEN (100 - discount)/100
                 ELSE 100/(100-discount)
                 END
               )
             ) OVER (
               PARTITION BY original_retail
               ORDER BY dt
             )
           ) * 100
         ) AS discount,
         TO_CHAR(
           original_retail
           * EXP(
               SUM(
                 LN(
                   CASE type
                   WHEN 1
                   THEN (100 - discount)/100
                   ELSE 100/(100-discount)
                   END
                 )
               ) OVER (
                 PARTITION BY original_retail
                 ORDER BY dt
               )
             ),
           'fm999990.00'
         ) AS promo_retail
  FROM   table_name
  UNPIVOT (
    (dt, discount) FOR type IN (
      (start_date, discount_percent) AS +1,
      (end_date,   discount_percent) AS -1
    )
  )
)
WHERE  start_date < end_date;
```

Which outputs:

| ORIGINAL_RETAIL | START_DATE | END_DATE | DISCOUNT | PROMO_RETAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 229 | 2023-12-10 00:00:00 | 2023-12-11 23:59:59 | 10 | 206.10 |
| 229 | 2023-12-12 00:00:00 | 2023-12-13 23:59:59 | 28 | 164.88 |
| 229 | 2023-12-14 00:00:00 | 2023-12-15 23:59:59 | 20 | 183.20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EWKcNC_U)

Comment: @Amit You have not included the "following data". Either, if you are just asking a minor clarification then, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77638135/edit) or, if this significantly changes the logic from the question then, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Don't try to post data (or code) as comments because it is almost always not displayed in an easily readable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate all dates and use the window functions and group by to group them back as follows:

```
WITH T AS (SELECT MIN(START_DATE) MN, MAX(END_DATE) MX FROM TEST),
ALL_DATES AS (SELECT MN + LEVEL -1 DT FROM T
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MX - MN + 1)
SELECT MIN(DT) AS START_DATE, 
       MAX(DT) AS END_DATE, 
       MX AS DISCOUNT,
       CASE WHEN MN = MX 
        THEN ORIGINAL_PRICE - (MX*ORIGINAL_PRICE/100)
        ELSE (ORIGINAL_PRICE - (MN*ORIGINAL_PRICE/100)) - ((ORIGINAL_PRICE - (MN*ORIGINAL_PRICE/100))*MX/100)
       END AS PROMO_RETAIL
FROM
    (SELECT T.*, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN MN <> PREV_MIN OR MX <> PREV_MAX  OR PREV_MAX IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
                    OVER (PARTITION BY T.ORIGINAL_PRICE ORDER BY T.DT) AS SM 
       FROM 
        (SELECT T.*,  
                LAG(MN) OVER (PARTITION BY T.ORIGINAL_PRICE ORDER BY T.DT) AS PREV_MIN,
                LAG(MX) OVER (PARTITION BY T.ORIGINAL_PRICE ORDER BY T.DT) AS PREV_MAX
           FROM 
            (SELECT D.DT, 
                    T.ORIGINAL_PRICE, 
                    MIN(DISCOUNT) MN, 
                    MAX(DISCOUNT) MX
               FROM ALL_DATES D 
               JOIN TEST T ON D.DT BETWEEN T.START_DATE AND T.END_DATE
            GROUP BY D.DT, T.ORIGINAL_PRICE) T) T)
GROUP BY ORIGINAL_PRICE, MX, MN, SM;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6y70g0p_)

Comment: This does not handle more than 2 rows of input [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LSoNnP5L)

Comment: @MT0 Fiddle you have provided in above comment is giving the correct output. Please describe me - in your point of view How it is incorrect. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: There should be 5 rows of output for the previous fiddle not 3 as there are 5 parts to the overlapping ranges. It should look like this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mxI8lPYX) Your solution will completely miss the day 2023-12-11 - 2023-12-12 and will only apply one 10% and one 20% discount and will fail to apply the second 10% discount from the third input row.