# Splitting of Overlapping date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have following data for promotion prices

| Promo_id | START_DATE | END_DATE | ITEM | SELLING_RETAIL | Change_Type | Change_Amount | Change_PERCENT | Change_Type_Desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | 14-12-2023 | 20-12-2023 | 100261942 | 229 | 0 | NULL | -10 | Percent Off |
| 2012 | 17-12-2023 | 22-12-2023 | 100261942 | 229 | 0 | NULL | -20 | Percent Off |
| 2013 | 14-12-2023 | 19-12-2023 | 100263219 | 279 | 2 | 200 | NULL | Fixed Price |
| 2021 | 17-12-2023 | 21-12-2023 | 100263219 | 279 | 1 | -100 | NULL | Amount off |

I want to split the above date range as mentioned below

| Item | START_DATE | END_DATE | Promo_Price | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100261942 | 14-Dec-23 | 16-Dec-23 | 206.1 | 10% on 229 |
| 100261942 | 17-Dec-23 | 20-Dec-23 | 164.88 | 20% on 206.1 --cumulative |
| 100261942 | 21-Dec-23 | 22-Dec-23 | 183.2 | 20% on 229 |
| 100263219 | 14-Dec-23 | 16-Dec-23 | 200 | Fixed Price |
| 100263219 | 17-Dec-23 | 19-Dec-23 | 100 | 100 Amount off on 200 |
| 100263219 | 20-Dec-23 | 21-Dec-23 | 179 | 100 Amount off on 279 |

tried below query for splitting date range. However I am not able to derive promo_retail based on change_type

```
with cte1 as      
(
  select promo_id, percent,  start_date as marker_date, 1 as type, b.item, b.SIMPLE_PROMO_RETAIL,      
   SELLING_RETAIL      
  from Table_A b      
  union all       
  select promo_id,percent, end_date+1 as marker_date, -1 as type, b.item, b.SIMPLE_PROMO_RETAIL      
, SELLING_RETAIL       
  from Table_A b       
),       
cte2 as (       
  select promo_id, marker_date as begin_date,     
    lead(marker_date) over (order by marker_date) - 1 as end_date,      
    item, percent, SIMPLE_PROMO_RETAIL, SELLING_RETAIL,      
    sum(type) over (order by marker_date) as periods       
  from cte1     
)      
select a.promo_id, a.begin_date, a.end_date,a.item ,a.SELLING_RETAIL, 
a.percent,periods            
from cte2 a           
where a.end_date is not null and periods > 0;
```

Comment: It will be better if you can create some fiddle and share your tries over there. Easy for answerer to solve it. https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: Hi @ORA-01017- I am new to this. Tried to create fiddle.  https://dbfiddle.uk/nLb4U7Yl . Basically Promo_Retail is driven from change_type. If change_type = 0 then apply percent off, if change_type = 1 then amount off (eg: 279-100) if change_type = 2 then fixed price (example: 200)  for change_type = 1 and 2, amount will be there in change_amount column and for 0 it is there in change_percent column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UNPIVOT` the start- and end-dates and then use a `MODEL` clause to process it row-by-row and calculate the base price, any fixed discounts and any percentage discounts and overwrite, add or multiply (respectively) those with the previous row and then use `LEAD` to find the end-date of the range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT item,
         dt AS start_date,
         LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY dt)
           - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS end_date,
         price
  FROM   (
    SELECT item,
           dt,
           price
    FROM   (
      SELECT item,
             promo_id,
             dt,
             selling_retail,
             change_type,
             change_sign,
             change_amount * change_sign AS change_amount,
             COALESCE(
               CASE change_sign
               WHEN 1
               THEN (100 + change_percent)/100
               ELSE 100/(100 + change_percent)
               END,
               1
             ) AS multiplier,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY dt, promo_id) AS rn
      FROM   table_name
      UNPIVOT (
        dt FOR change_sign IN (
          start_date AS +1,
          end_date   AS -1
        )
      ) u
    )
    MODEL
      PARTITION BY (item)
      DIMENSION BY (rn)
      MEASURES (
        promo_id,
        dt,
        selling_retail,
        change_type,
        change_sign,
        change_amount,
        multiplier,
        0 AS base_price,
        0 AS offset_price,
        0 AS discount,
        0 AS price
      )
      RULES (
        base_price[1]    = CASE
                           WHEN change_type[1] = 2
                           AND  change_sign[1] = 1
                           THEN change_amount[1]
                           ELSE selling_retail[1]
                           END,
        base_price[rn>1] = CASE
                           WHEN change_type[cv()] = 2
                           AND  change_sign[cv()] = 1
                           THEN change_amount[cv()]
                           WHEN change_type[cv()] = 2
                           AND  change_sign[cv()] = -1
                           THEN selling_retail[cv()]
                           ELSE base_price[cv()-1]
                           END,
        offset_price[rn] = CASE
                           WHEN change_type[cv()] = 1
                           THEN change_amount[cv()]
                           ELSE 0
                           END + COALESCE(offset_price[cv()-1], 0),
        discount[rn]     = multiplier[cv()] * COALESCE(discount[cv()-1], 1),
        price[rn]        = base_price[cv()] * discount[cv()] + offset_price[cv()]
      )
  )
)
WHERE start_date < end_date;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Promo_id, START_DATE, END_DATE, ITEM, SELLING_RETAIL, Change_Type, Change_Amount, Change_PERCENT, Change_Type_Desc) AS
SELECT 2011, DATE '2023-12-14', DATE '2023-12-20', 100261942, 229, 0, NULL, -10,  'Percent Off' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2012, DATE '2023-12-17', DATE '2023-12-22', 100261942, 229, 0, NULL, -20,  'Percent Off' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2013, DATE '2023-12-14', DATE '2023-12-19', 100263219, 279, 2, 200,  NULL, 'Fixed Price' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2021, DATE '2023-12-17', DATE '2023-12-21', 100263219, 279, 1, -100, NULL, 'Amount off'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM | START_DATE | END_DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100261942 | 2023-12-14 00:00:00 | 2023-12-16 23:59:59 | 206.1 |
| 100261942 | 2023-12-17 00:00:00 | 2023-12-19 23:59:59 | 164.88 |
| 100261942 | 2023-12-20 00:00:00 | 2023-12-21 23:59:59 | 183.2 |
| 100263219 | 2023-12-14 00:00:00 | 2023-12-16 23:59:59 | 200 |
| 100263219 | 2023-12-17 00:00:00 | 2023-12-18 23:59:59 | 100 |
| 100263219 | 2023-12-19 00:00:00 | 2023-12-20 23:59:59 | 179 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/reeqJzCu)

Comment: Thanks @MT0.  for item 100263219 - the date split should be 14th to 16th Dec then 17th Dec to 19th Dec and then 20 Dec to 21st Dec......... For item : 100261942, the date split should be: 14th to 16th Dec then 17th Dec to 20th Dec  and from 21st Dec to 22nd dec

Comment: @Amit In Oracle, a `DATE` has both date and time components so when you state that the `end_date` is 16th December you are stating that it is midnight on the 16th December. If you actually mean that it ends at 23:59:59 on 16th December then add 1 to all your end dates before unpivoting [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ByxIlYT8).

Comment: Thank you very much. this solves the problem. Really Appreciate your help